# When launching the Screencast tool I receive a message "Application Blocked by Java Security"

Tags: droid-explorer

When I try to launch the Screencast tool in Droid Explorer I am presented with this dialog.

[image: Application Blocked by Java Secturity]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I am the lead developer of Droid Explorer*

The Screencast application is out of the control of Droid Explorer development team as it is a [3rd party project](https://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/). The project actually seems like it has been abandoned.

I found a fork of the code on Github that looks like it is under more active development: [https://github.com/xSAVIKx/AndroidScreencast](https://github.com/xSAVIKx/AndroidScreencast/)

---

The workaround to get it working is only a few steps:

1. Open the Java Control Panel (Located in the Windows Control Panel) 
   [image: Control Panel]
2. Next click the Security Tab and Click on **Edit Site List...**
   [image: Security Tab]
3. Click **Add** and enter http://androidscreencast.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/AndroidScreencast/dist/androidscreencast.jnlp (This may change in the future for the github fork)
   [image: Url]
4. Click **OK**
5. Click **Continue**
6. Click **OK** to close the Java Security Control Panel

> Note: When you launch the Screencast plugin again, you will be
>   presented with a warning because the application is not signed by the
>   developer.
>
> [image: Digital signature]